# reading differet date formats in java

Tags: java, date

I have the below program in which the date patterns in not reflected correctly that is i execute it i get the date formats incorrect for first two dates .

please advise how can i make changes in the array named datePatternsOfUk so that it should work for all the dates

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;

public class DateFormattingTest {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd/MM/yyyy");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println ("03/20/2020-->:" + extractDate("03/20/2020") );
         System.out.println ("2033-05-01-->:" + extractDate("2033-05-01") );
        System.out.println ("08-05-34-->:" + extractDate("08-05-34") );
         System.out.println ("30-09-2013 -->:" + extractDate("30-09-2013") );

    public static Date extractDate(String dateStr) {

        String[] datePatternsOfUk = { "d-M-yy", "d-M-yyyy", "d/M/yy", "d/M/yyyy","dd-MM-yy", "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MMM-yy","dd-MMM-yyyy","dd-MM-yyyy",
                "dd/MM/yy","dd/MMM/yy","dd/MMM/yyyy"};

        Date date = null;

        try {
            date = DateUtils.parseDate(dateStr, datePatternsOfUk);
        }
        catch (Exception except) {
                except.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }

}
```

upon execution i get the below results which are not correctly

```
03/20/2020-->:Tue Aug 03 00:00:00 IST 2021
2033-05-01-->:Thu Nov 23 00:00:00 IST 2006
08-05-34-->:Mon May 08 00:00:00 IST 2034
30-09-2013 -->:Mon Sep 30 00:00:00 IST 2013
```

folks please advise how to overcome from this

Comment: try setLenient(false) with SimpleDateFormat

Comment: @Koem Thanks for the reply please advise where to edit in the above mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final String[] datePatternsOfUk = { "d-M-yy", "d-M-yyyy", "d/M/yy", "d/M/yyyy",
        "dd-MM-yy", "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MMM-yy", "dd-MMM-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yy",
        "dd/MMM/yy", "dd/MMM/yyyy" };

public static Date extractDate(String dateStr) {

    for (String pattern : datePatternsOfUk) {

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            sdf.setLenient(false);
            return sdf.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (Exception except) {
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

your first date won't get parsed because "M/d/yyyy" is missing.

Comment: i get exception for this java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "03/20/2020" and java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2033-05-01"

Comment: 03/20/2020 is dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: you should get many exceptions because this tries different (and wrong) patterns on all the date strings until one that's matching is found. comment out except.printStackTrace() to see what's returned only.

Comment: @TarunVerma Please work a little harder. This correct Answer by koem gives you the basic solution: You have inputs which do not match any of your specified parsing patterns. This Answer gave you one more additional parsing pattern to match one of your problem inputs. You *really* should be able to do the rest. Furthermore, your Question is a duplicate; this topic of multiple parsing patterns has been covered many times already on StackOverflow. Search before posting.